# Problems with extending session "datetime is not JSON serializable"

Tags: django, django-sessions, django-1.8

In the view I have:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
self.request.session.set_expiry(now + timedelta(days=365))
```

but it raises

> datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 24, 17, 19, 0, 826661, tzinfo=) is not
>   JSON serializable

I've found one solution:

```
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

but it works only in Chrome ... in Safari django raises error

> UnpicklingError at / invalid load key, '{'.

Any suggestions?

---

### Workaround #1

```
self.request.session.set_expiry(int(timedelta(days=365).total_seconds()))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry):

> set_expiry(value)
>
> Sets the expiration time for the session. You can pass a number of different values:
>
> - If value is an integer, the session will expire after that many seconds of inactivity. For example, calling request.session.set_expiry(300) would make the session expire in 5 minutes.
> - If value is a datetime or timedelta object, the session will expire at that specific date/time. Note that datetime and timedelta values are only serializable if you are using the PickleSerializer.
> - If value is 0, the user’s session cookie will expire when the user’s Web browser is closed.
> - If value is None, the session reverts to using the global session expiry policy.

So, you are getting the expected behavior. If you want to pass a datetime to session.set_expiry, you have to use PickleSerializer.
In my opinion, the workaround you proposed, it's actually the best solution, and keep using the JSONSerializer.

Comment: Oh, I have looked at declaration of set_expiry, ... but you are flattering me ... so the best answer - accepted :D